# How do i set the default index to 0 when i bind to combobox?

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I am using MVVM in my application and binding combobox to my collection. However when i run it the combobox doesn't have any selected index and it shows a ugly emtpy box. How do i get past this issue?

This is my code :-

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPasswordQuestion"  ItemsSource="{Binding PasswordQuestionList}"  DisplayMemberPath="SiteTermsXItemsName" SelectedValuePath="SiteTermsXItemId" SelectedValue="{Binding SignUpUser.PasswordQuestionId}" Margin="97,210,247,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PasswordQuestionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmbPasswordQuestion}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBox>
```

I am not able to set the `SelectedIndex = 0` directly in xaml as i am binding the collection run time.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to set `SignUpUser.PasswordQuestionId` to the id of the first item in the combobox right after you initialized the `PasswordQuestionList` property. And the binding will do the rest.

Comment: Silly me!! Thanks how could i not think of it..! Thanks anyways